# Matrix polynomial manipulation

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices

Skimming the next material of my book, I saw this question:

> If $$A^5+A^4+A^3+A^2=-\frac{1}{2}I$$
>    Then, determine $$(2A^3+I)^{-1}$$

The book says the answer is
$$A^2+A+I$$
I only have basic concepts of matrices (Multiplication, addition, non-commutativity, associativity, and the identity matrix). Also, the only thing I know about inversion is that if $A^{-1}=B$, then $AB=I$.  How may I approach this problem? (Of course, if some heavier machinery is needed to answer this question, I will be happy to learn about it, so don't restrict to the above list)

Comment: you tried something?? you atleast checked if given answer is correct by considering $(A^2+A+I)(2A^3+I)$??

Comment: Yes, by ordinary algebra treating the matrix as a variable. But you get $$2A^5+2A^4+2A^3+A^2+A+I$$

Comment: but that is not equal to $I$ right?

Comment: It is left to verify that $$A=A^2+I$$

Comment: But you can not say that is true or false... right??? so your inverse is wrong i believe....

Answer (score 2):

It's not true for the $1 \times 1$ real matrix that satisfies the constraint.  Let $\alpha$ be the real root of the polynomial $x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+\frac{1}{2}=0$.  And let $$A=[\alpha]_{1 \times 1} \approx [-1.15889].$$

Then $$(2A^3+I)^{-1}=[2\alpha^3+1]^{-1}=[\tfrac{1}{2\alpha^3+1}] \approx [-0.473291].$$

However, $A^2+A+I=[\alpha^2+\alpha+1] \approx [1.18414].$

Comment: you took so much pain to say that this is wrong :)

Comment: Also this counterexample extends to the counterexample $\alpha I$ for arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: yes yes... I agree!

Comment: So, is there some way to solve this?(as stated)

Answer (score 1):

$$(2A^3+I)(A^2+A+I)=\color{red}{2A^5+2A^4+2A^3}+A^2+A+I=$$

$$=\color{red}{-I-2A}+A^2+A+I=A^2-A$$

If the answer's correct, that means that

$$A^2-A=I$$

which I can't see how to deduce from the giving stuff, so I think the answer in that book's wrong.

Comment: So, in order for the problem to have sense, leaving just $I$ in the RHS,the condition's LHS should have factorizable so that it asks for the inverse of some factor?

Comment: @chubakueno, I really don't understand you. The question makes sense, the answer doesn't.

Comment: I was saying *has sense* in the sense of *it is possible to answer it*.